# Ubuntu 20.04 VM instance hangs after nvidia driver installation

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, virtual-machine

I have IBM VM instance with Tesla v100 32gb gpu for machine learning. After installing nvidia driver VM works fine 10-15min and then it hangs. If i`m trying to re-login, vm simply not responding. Only reboot via VM management panel helps, but then again it works only for 10-15min and situation repeats. I successfully uninstalled drivers but that didnt change anything. Any tips what can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

After video driver installation system power management was activating sleep mode.
command to ckeck it:

```
systemctl status sleep.target
```

result:

- sleep.target - Sleep

  - Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sleep.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  - Active: inactive (dead)

    - Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

command to switch off sleep:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

result:

- Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sleep.target → /dev/null.
  Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/suspend.target → /dev/null.
  Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/hibernate.target → /dev/null.
  Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/hybrid-sleep.target → /dev/null.